# IIS: Adding sub directory (Visual Studio aplication) to websites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, web-config, directory, virtual

I have a couple of projects/application on IIS under the foler *RootFolder*, and I am trying to add one more application to this foler. I added a virtual directory called *ProjectFolder* to the *RootFolder* and linked it to the location of my new application in the *wwwroot* folder. However, I keep getting the error below when trying to navigate to the page on the web browser.

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to > service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 43:     </authorization>
Line 44:     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 45:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 46:       <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
Line 47:     </authentication>
```

> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RootFolder\ProjectFolder\web.config    Line: 45

To be sure it is a problem with my application, I copied the content of another application that is working well onto my *ProjectFolder*, but the same error shows. I have also tried right clicking on the virtual directory folder and selecting change to application (this changed the icon of the the virtual directory folder. However, none of the icons of the other applications that are on my ISS and are working look anything like this new icon), yet this give the same error.
I was thinking of maybe deleting this virtual directory and recreating it but when I right click on the folder, I have no option for properties or to delete the directory.

Can anyone help PLEASE?

Thanks